# Error loading type lib/dll for MFC

Tags: dll, mfc

I have just inherited a project that is using MFC. I am currently using Visual Studio 2012.

The original project included some dlls. However when I compile, I get a "Error loading type library/DLL." Apparently, it comes from the #import statement under StdAfx.h

I have read some other forums, which describes the need of using a .tlb file, but I could not find it anywhere in the project.

Apologies as I am quite new to MFC. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: #import means that the project is using some third-party libraries/controls. Are you sure these exist (are installed on the machine where you compile the project)?
What are the missing #imported libraries exactly, maybe this can help?

Comment: Alright I got the problem. Apparently I didn't place the dlls in the correct location. Thanks for the help!